# OSMDroid - Text overlay

Tags: osmdroid

I have a map of my country divider to touristic regions (PathOverlay), I wanna be able to have the name of every region above it, with just plain text, no bubbles no anything.
I've already searched how to do this but all I found was `ItemizedOverlayWithFocus` in the svn trunk of osmdroid.
Does anyone have any idea how to add simple text on the map (with latitude and longitude of course) ?

Answer (score 0):

Sub-class Overlay (as for instance a "SimpleTextOverlay").

In the constructor or with setters, initialize your text, its position (GeoPoint), and the Paint to be used.

Then implement draw method this way:

```
@Override protected void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow) {
   if (shadow) return;
   //Get the screen position: 
   final Projection pj = mapView.getProjection();
   pj.toMapPixels(geoPosition, screenPosition);
   //And draw your text at screenPosition:
   canvas.drawText(text, screenPosition.x, screenPosition.y, paint);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer posted here

[How to add text below/above in the middle of the polyline in osmdroid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40935351/how-to-add-text-below-above-in-the-middle-of-the-polyline-in-osmdroid/40943040#40943040)

Use the Marker overlay class, which was added to osmdroid somewhere around v5.2.
Set the title, then set the icon to null, then add it to the map (in that order)

Answer (score 0):

```
distanceMarker = new Marker(mapView);
            distanceMarker.setIcon(null);
            distanceMarker.setTextIcon(distance);
            distanceMarker.setOnMarkerClickListener((marker, mapView) -> true);
            GeoPoint p3 = new GeoPoint((loc.getLatitude()+poi.getLat())/2,(loc.getLongitude()+poi.getLon())/2);
            distanceMarker.setPosition(p3);
            mapView.getOverlayManager().add(distanceMarker);
```